# how to add contact group to my own account in Android 4.2

Tags: android, contacts, account

I'm developing an Android account app. Now I can add my own account in Android.
But when I open the Contacts app and switch to group pager, it shows me "**No groups. To create groups you need an account.**". So how to let android know my account can add a group?

Below is my xml file:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <!-- The sync service -->
    <service
            android:name="com.snail.android.sync.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/contacts_sync_adapter"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE"
                android:resource="@xml/contacts"/>

    </service>
```

contacts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContactsAccountType>
    <EditSchema>
        <!--
            Name:
            - maxOccurs must be 1
            - No types.

            - Currently all the supportsXxx attributes must be true, but here's the plan for the
              future:
              (There's some hardcoded assumptions in the contact editor, which is one reason
              for the above restriction)

                - "Family name" and "Given name" must be supported.
                    - All sync adapters must support structured name. "display name only" is not
                      supported.
                      -> Supporting this would require relatively large changes to
                         the contact editor.

                - Fields are decided from the attributes:
                    StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME         if supportsDisplayName == true
                    StructuredName.PREFIX               if supportsPrefix == true
                    StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME          (always)
                    StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME          if supportsPrefix == true
                    StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME           (always)
                    StructuredName.SUFFIX               if supportsSuffix == true
                    StructuredName.PHONETIC_FAMILY_NAME if supportsPhoneticFamilyName == true
                    StructuredName.PHONETIC_MIDDLE_NAME if supportsPhoneticMiddleName == true
                    StructuredName.PHONETIC_GIVEN_NAME  if supportsPhoneticGivenName == true

                - DataKind.PSEUDO_MIME_TYPE_DISPLAY_NAME  is always added.
                - DataKind.PSEUDO_MIME_TYPE_PHONETIC_NAME is added
                  if any of supportsPhoneticXxx == true
        -->
        <!-- Fallback/Google definition.  Supports all. -->
        <DataKind
                kind="name"
                maxOccurs="1"
                supportsDisplayName="true"
                supportsPrefix="true"
                supportsMiddleName="true"
                supportsSuffix="true"
                supportsPhoneticFamilyName="true"
                supportsPhoneticMiddleName="true"
                supportsPhoneticGivenName="true"
                >
        </DataKind>

        <!-- Exchange definition.  No display-name, no phonetic-middle.
        <DataKind kind="name"
            supportsDisplayName="false"
            supportsPrefix="true"
            supportsMiddleName="true"
            supportsSuffix="true"
            supportsPhoneticFamilyName="true"
            supportsPhoneticMiddleName="false"
            supportsPhoneticGivenName ="true"
            >
        </DataKind>
        -->

        <!--
            Photo:
            - maxOccurs must be 1
            - No types.
        -->
        <DataKind
                kind="photo"
                maxOccurs="1"/>

        <!--
            Phone definition.
            - "is secondary?" is inferred from type.
        -->
        <!-- Fallback, Google definition.  -->
        <DataKind kind="phone">
            <!-- Note: Google type doesn't have obsolete ones -->
            <Type type="mobile"/>
            <Type type="home"/>
            <Type type="work"/>
            <Type type="fax_work"/>
            <Type type="fax_home"/>
            <Type type="pager"/>
            <Type type="other"/>
            <Type type="custom"/>
            <Type type="callback"/>
            <Type type="car"/>
            <Type type="company_main"/>
            <Type type="isdn"/>
            <Type type="main"/>
            <Type type="other_fax"/>
            <Type type="radio"/>
            <Type type="telex"/>
            <Type type="tty_tdd"/>
            <Type type="work_mobile"/>
            <Type type="work_pager"/>
            <Type type="assistant"/>
            <Type type="mms"/>
        </DataKind>

        <!-- Exchange definition.
        <DataKind kind="phone" >
            <Type type="home" maxOccurs="2" />
            <Type type="mobile" maxOccurs="1" />
            <Type type="work" maxOccurs="2" />
            <Type type="fax_work" maxOccurs="1" />
            <Type type="fax_home" maxOccurs="1" />
            <Type type="pager" maxOccurs="1" />
            <Type type="car" maxOccurs="1" />
            <Type type="company_main" maxOccurs="1" />
            <Type type="mms" maxOccurs="1" />
            <Type type="radio" maxOccurs="1" />
            <Type type="assistant" maxOccurs="1" />
        </DataKind>
        -->

        <!--
            Email
        -->
        <!-- Fallback/Google definition.  -->
        <DataKind kind="email">
            <!-- Note: Google type doesn't have obsolete ones -->
            <Type type="home"/>
            <Type type="work"/>
            <Type type="other"/>
            <Type type="mobile"/>
            <Type type="custom"/>
        </DataKind>

        <!--
            Exchange definition.
            - Same definition as "fallback" except for maxOccurs=3
        <DataKind kind="email" maxOccurs="3" >
            <Type type="home" />
            <Type type="work" />
            <Type type="other" />
            <Type type="mobile" />
            <Type type="custom" />
        </DataKind>
        -->

        <!--
            Nickname
            - maxOccurs must be 1
            - No types.
        -->
        <DataKind
                kind="nickname"
                maxOccurs="1"/>

        <!--
            Im:
             - The TYPE column always stores Im.TYPE_OTHER (defaultValues is always set)
             - The user-selected type is stored in Im.PROTOCOL
        -->
        <!-- Fallback, Google definition.  -->
        <DataKind kind="im">
            <Type type="aim"/>
            <Type type="msn"/>
            <Type type="yahoo"/>
            <Type type="skype"/>
            <Type type="qq"/>
            <Type type="google_talk"/>
            <Type type="icq"/>
            <Type type="jabber"/>
            <Type type="custom"/>
        </DataKind>

        <!-- Exchange definition.
        <DataKind kind="im" maxOccurs="3" >
            <Type type="aim" />
            <Type type="msn" />
            <Type type="yahoo" />
            <Type type="skype" />
            <Type type="qq" />
            <Type type="google_talk" />
            <Type type="icq" />
            <Type type="jabber" />
            <Type type="custom" />
        </DataKind>
        -->

        <!--
            Postal address.
        -->
        <!-- Fallback/Google definition.  Not structured. -->
        <DataKind
                kind="postal"
                needsStructured="false">
            <Type type="home"/>
            <Type type="work"/>
            <Type type="other"/>
            <Type type="custom"/>
        </DataKind>

        <!-- Exchange definition.  Structured.
        <DataKind kind="postal" needsStructured="true" >
            <Type type="work" />
            <Type type="home" />
            <Type type="other" />
        </DataKind>
        -->

        <!--
            Organization:
            - Fields are fixed: COMPANY, TITLE
            - maxOccurs must be 1
            - No types.
        -->
        <DataKind
                kind="organization"
                maxOccurs="1"/>

        <!--
            Website:
            - No types.
        -->
        <DataKind kind="website"/>

        <!--
            Below kinds have nothing configurable.
            - No types are supported.
            - maxOccurs must be 1
        -->
        <DataKind
                kind="sip_address"
                maxOccurs="1"/>
        <DataKind
                kind="note"
                maxOccurs="1"/>

        <!--
            Google/Exchange supports it, but fallback doesn't.
        <DataKind kind="group_membership" maxOccurs="1" />
        -->

        <!--
            Event
        -->
        <DataKind
                kind="event"
                dateWithTime="false">
            <Type
                    type="birthday"
                    maxOccurs="1"
                    yearOptional="true"/>
            <Type type="anniversary"/>
            <Type type="other"/>
            <Type type="custom"/>
        </DataKind>

        <!--
            Exchange definition.  dateWithTime is needed only for Exchange.
        <DataKind kind="event" dateWithTime="true">
            <Type type="birthday" maxOccurs="1" />
        </DataKind>
        -->

        <!--
            Relationship
        -->
        <DataKind kind="relationship">
            <Type type="assistant"/>
            <Type type="brother"/>
            <Type type="child"/>
            <Type type="domestic_partner"/>
            <Type type="father"/>
            <Type type="friend"/>
            <Type type="manager"/>
            <Type type="mother"/>
            <Type type="parent"/>
            <Type type="partner"/>
            <Type type="referred_by"/>
            <Type type="relative"/>
            <Type type="sister"/>
            <Type type="spouse"/>
            <Type type="custom"/>
        </DataKind>
    </EditSchema>
</ContactsAccountType>
```

Comment: It's an Android bug: See https://github.com/rfc2822/davdroid/issues/48#issuecomment-31424593

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this with the stock intent and contact picker system